# What is an annual raw composite image?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am reading [Landsat 8 Collection 1 Tier 1 Annual Raw Composite](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C01_T1_ANNUAL_RAW)

My query is: what is the intuition behind the Annual Raw composite ?

My understanding is : We take ***all*** scenes across ***all*** path and rows in the relevant year and then compute an average ?

Is that what an Annual Raw composite is ?

My confusion is : If I average across ***all*** paths / rows, the resulting picture has no meaning/intuition?

Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what the EE catalogue says:

> These composites are created from all the scenes in each annual period
> beginning from the first day of the year and continuing to the last
> day of the year. All the images from each year are included in the
> composite, with the most recent pixel as the composite value.

It is not giving you an average, it gives you the most recent, non-masked, pixel value. Note that the pixels from different dates but at the same location have been composed into a single value. Values from different locations are not mixed up in any way.

I do have to say, I'm not convinced this is a very useful image collection. You typically do this composing yourself, as you want to have more control in how they're made.

Comment: I would like to say that there is no path or row number. That's my main confusion. That's what made me think that ***all*** path/rows have been averaged over. I guess I was mistaken. How exactly does one use this composite? Now it looks like we have one yearly composite for all pixels in each path / row combination?  How do I extract the composite for a given path and row? In the example on the mentioned page they do a Maps.setCenter. Is there a way to create a composite for a given path / row ?

Comment: Now that I think about it, this composite is a way of taking the ***most recent snapshot*** of a given pixel. That's the intuition behind this. Does anyone here agree / disagree?

Comment: This is how we may create this composite at a given  path and row : ```var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_ANNUAL_RAW')
  .filterDate('2021', '2022')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 44))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 34));```